# Condition working for text but not bar in vega-lite power bi chart

Tags: conditional-statements, powerbi, vega-lite

I have the Deneb custom chart in Power BI. I have been building a chart and have it mostly working. What I'm struggling with is having a few conditional marks on the chart. I have this working for a text mark but the same code doesn't seem to work with a bar mark.

```
{
      "mark": {"type": "text"},
      "encoding": {
          "text": {
          "field": "SELECT_LNGSched"
        },
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.SELECT_LNGSched == true", "value": 1},
          "value": 0
        }
      }
    }
```

This seems to work and I'm able to change SELECT_LNGSched from true to false and I can make it so that the text turns on and off.

```
{
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "SELECT_LNGSched"
        },
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 350000]},
          "field": "SCHED_SPOTCARGOLOADING"
        },
        "opacity": {
        "condition": {
          "test": "datum.SELECT_LNGSched == true", "value": 1},"value": 0
        }
      }
    }
```

this code does not seem to work and the bar always has an opacity of 0 no matter if SELECT_LNGSched is true or false or anything else.

Am I not able to conditionally set the opacity of bars?

I have tried

- making my SELECT_LNGSched a number instead of a bool
- including the opacity within the mark or the y sections
- creating a different field to use as a condition

Comment: Can you share a full spec and test data or a sample .pbix with your expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that is working and you can compare your code with this:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Bar chart with text labels. Set domain to make the frame cover the labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28, "SELECT_LNGSched": true},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55, "SELECT_LNGSched": true},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43, "SELECT_LNGSched": false}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [0, 60]}}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.SELECT_LNGSched == true", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.25
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "baseline": "middle", "dx": 3},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.SELECT_LNGSched == true", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.25
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

Adam from APB Reports.